# How to check with JavaScript if web server port is being blocked

Tags: javascript, nginx, websocket

I use NginX proxy to pipe data to and fro trough WebSocket between web application and Node.js application.

In doing this, all requests to open the webpage and PHP functions would route through port 80 and all data coming and going through WebSocket would direct to port 8080 or 8008.

The problem: port 8080 has been blocked in mobile network so people cannot use mobile phone (Android) to run the web app and port 8008 was blocked in some offices and homes so user cannot use PC to pipe and receive data through the app.

I’m able to set NginX proxy to receive those data separately, but how do I check which port is being blocked at the time. I’ve tried this workaround but it isn’t working:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://62.57.141.143:8008/') || new WebSocket('ws:// 62.57.141.143:8080/');
```

I want something like this:

```
var socket;
if ( port 8080 is blocked ) {
    socket = new WebSocket('ws://62.57.141.143:8008/')
} else {
    socket = new WebSocket('ws://62.57.141.143:8080/')
}
```

Thank you and hope I make myself clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I can find the solution.

```
function openWebsocket(url){
    try {
        socket = new WebSocket(url);
        socket.onopen = function(){
            console.log('Socket is now open.');
        };
        socket.onerror = function (error) {
            console.error('There was an un-identified Web Socket error');
        };
        socket.onmessage = function (message) {
            console.info("Message: %o", message.data);
        };
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Sorry, the web socket at "%s" is un-available', url);
    }
}

openWebsocket("ws://62.57.141.143:8008");
openWebsocket("ws://62.57.141.143:8080");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to it. If you get an error, fall back to another port.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using nginx, take advantage of the proxy_pass:

Users will still connect to port 80, and nginx proxy it to port 8080.

Example: Proxy pass everything under `/socket.io/` to `http://127.0.0.1:8080`.

```
location /socket.io/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

For client-side, try this:

If the client can connect, the networkPort80xx variable will be set to true.

In your web application:

```
<script src="//62.57.141.143:8080/detect.js"></script>
<script src="//62.57.141.143:8008/detect.js"></script>
<script>
var networkPort8080 = false,
    networkPort8008 = false;
if (window.NetworkPort8080) { networkPort8080=true; }
if (window.NetworkPort8008) { networkPort8008=true; }
var socket;
if (networkPort8080) {
    socket = new WebSocket('ws://62.57.141.143:8080/');
} else if (networkPort8008) {
    socket = new WebSocket('ws://62.57.141.143:8008/');
}
</script>
```

In 62.57.141.143:8080/detect.js

```
window.NetworkPort8080=function(){return true;}
```

In 62.57.141.143:8008/detect.js

```
window.NetworkPort8000=function(){return true;}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already did this. I just need to check client side.

Comment: I don't know why you need to use 8080/8008, because WS:// can connect on 80 via proxy_pass. Anyway, try the client side code.